# What is the problem with my question about sand generators in Minecraft 1.7.10?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, minecraft

I have asked [a question about sand generators](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330536/is-there-any-working-sand-generator-in-minecraft-version-1-7-10?noredirect=1#comment470546_330536) recently, asking for a design of a sand duplicator that still works in 1.7.10.

However, I got a rather negative reaction, and I think that it is going to be closed soon. I was told that this question is not within the scope of this SE.

I would like to know the reason of it being outside of the scope of this SE if it actually is and ways to fix it if any do exist.

I have a very clear problem to solve that is surely related to gaming, that is stated in a very detailed way, and, apparently, there aren't a lot of solutions for this question, if they even exist.

So, would be glad to hear why is my question bad.

Answer (score -7):

We want askers to try to solve their problem before asking, including online research. See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference. When googling "[Minecraft 1.7.10 sand duplicator](https://www.google.com/search?q=Minecraft+1.7.10+sand+duplicator)" (the first search term that came to my mind after reading your question), the first result is a not very helpful Minecraft forum link. The [second result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqMoq5Bq13Q) is a video with a world download that I personally tried: It contains a working sand duplicator for 1.7.10. It wasn't very hard to find.

Secondly, it's a too broad question. That might just be my opinion (and the two others whose close vote reasons I sadly can't completely see), but as I see it, the only acceptable answer to it would either be to find a sand duplicator online (which is your job) or to construct a completely new one, which is a big project. Someone might be willing to do it, but we're mainly here to help you with problems you encounter while doing projects yourself. We don't deliver complete project results ready to be copied.

Comment: An additional point is that asking us to find something that meets your criteria is a recommendation, and off-topic.

Comment: @Frank I 100% don't understand how this question is a recommendation in any way. I read it as asking if there is a way to build a sand generator in 1.7.10, and if not, how far do you need to back-version to build one. This is a fairly well documented glitch that exist entirely within the game, which to me, does not constitute a recommendation question

Comment: @Unionhawk Considering the asker wants a link to a working generator, that's literally what a recommendation is.  That said, I've not voted to close in any sense; it seems borderline enough in the Minecraft space that I believe it's more in that line of expertise.

Comment: @Frank that's an extremely technical nitpick and you know it. The difference between "how do I do this thing in a game" and "can you give me a link to show me how to do this thing in a game" is, in my opinion, meaningless. That said, I would recommend an edit to address this critique.

Comment: @Unionhawk It's the epitome of the XY problem, yes.  But, again, changing that is changing the intent, and that's isn't something other editors can do.  Call it a nitpick if you want.

Comment: @Frank this is why I'm merely recommending an edit to the asker rather than making it myself

Comment: @Unionhawk So, we've been in agreement the whole time.

Comment: This is the same problem we were just talking about in another meta thread not 1 day ago. The rules state you can't ask for recommendations but people still think it's okay to do so. Asking how to do X is different than give me a link that shows me how to do X.

Comment: @Fabian My search query has revealed a bunch of redstone schemes that were designed for previous versions of Minecraft and forum threads pointing out that all the glitches were fixed. To find a working solution myself I would have studied each of them very closely. Which means trying to recreate each of them in a testing world, making sure that I copy the scheme as in the video and that it is not my fault if it doesn't work. However, I suspect that if such a thing is possible and practical, someone has already done this before and found a working solution, hence I asked my question.

Comment: Of course, I did not ask for a link, I would make much more use of an explanation of the glitches abused and the redstone behind.

Comment: Did you believe the claims that every way was fixed? If yes, you wouldn't have asked. If no, I would have expected a question like "here (link) someone claims xyz, is it true?" or "does abc exist in version 42.1337?".